# One icon is missing in font awesome in Windows

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome

I'm currently using a Windows 7 VM to test my website in IE11. My website uses font awesome and glyphicons. All icons are loaded as expected except for a single one.

```
<button type="submit">
    <i class="fa fa-cart-plus fa-2x"></i>
</button>
```

Testing in Firefox and Chrome in my Linux Mint machine, all icons render correctly. But both IE and Firefox in Windows show this single icon as a box.

[image]

I noticed that in Linux, the `.woff2` file was being used while the `.woff` version was used in Windows. Font Awesome CSS and fonts are being served locally, not from a CDN. Could this make any difference? This missing icon shows correctly on [font awesome's website](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/cart-plus/).

I found a few similar answers in Stack Overflow, most are old and I couldn't fix this because I don't even know where to start. How can I fix this missing icon?

Comment: Have you attempted to point at a CDN to see if this resolves the issue?

Comment: I did, my it doesn't solve the problem, it skips it and I would rather server a local font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also having this issue with Chrome in a local environment (Probably more than that but can't be bothered to fully test) - I suspect the latest release has gotten messed up.

I've built a version using the fa-stack method below, just needs a little css for positioning but works fine:

HTML

```
<a role="button" class="btn btn-primary">
<span class="fa-stack">
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-stack-2x"></i>
<i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-primary"></i>
</span>&nbsp;New</a>
```

CSS

```
.fa-primary{
position: relative;
color: #1a9dff;
font-size: 0.5em !important;
top:-4px;
left:2px !important;
}
```

Edit:  I've had to tweak the css for use with the CDN version of FontAwesome - Further suspect the download package and the CDN do not match

[See this codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOJdxb)

This will overlay a plus icon of the colour of your choosing over the shopping cart icon. (Edit: Apologies for my poor indentation, first time answering!)

I'll point out that something similar happened with Bootstrap a few months ago, I updated the core files from 3.1.1 to 3.3.4 (or something) and it completely destroyed my layouts, though using the CDN used on bootstrap's homepage everything was fine, just not the downloadable package.

Basically, hang about for a bit and I'm sure they'll sort it, even the pros make mistakes - Use the same source as on working examples until the download package gets fixed if you're desperate to use it.

Comment: I like the way you think. I'll accept this answer if you'd be willing to add a minimum working example to show of your icon.

Comment: Gah - I'm supposed to be working :P let me just add a Bootply to my answer

Comment: It's not centered hehe. But it'll do. :) The good thing about this solution is that it allows you to make your add button the way you want. I kind of dislike how the default one looks like. Also, your example was not working because it lacked font awesome. I just wanted the answer to be complete :) thanks

Comment: No worries, I always wanted to use the fa-stack approach just not had an excuse until now as I wanted the same icon as you lol

Answer (score 2):

You're serving an older version of font awesome font files on Linux vs your Windows machine. This icon (fa-cart-plus) is only available starting in v4.3 (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/cart-plus/). Make sure both machines are being served fontawesome 4.3 font files and it'll work fine.

CDN is always helpful to use, but it's not going to show you the root cause of your problem.

Comment: Using the CDN works, but it comes with the downside of having to do an extra request for an external stylesheet. I installed fontawesome using bower and the version is 4.3.0, the latest one right now. I will try to download everything from the source then.

Comment: But you are correct. All icons from the 4.3 update are not working here.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this `CSS` in your webpage

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
```